# Laravel - enum type taking only the first option

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I'm work in a simple lavarel project with one database(MySQL) table. That table 
have a column named category and it type is a enum['Math','Biology','Arts']. But when I try to create a row in it, the column category is filled with the first option every time. What I have to do to solve that issue?

Comment: Show your code and table definition in order to get help.

Comment: My bet is you forgot to add your enum column as fillable in your eloquent model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ENUM type column you have to set a Default value, and if you don't specify Default value than it will take the first one as a Default value.

Comment: Default values seem to be the effect, not the cause or answer as the OP is attempting to insert a value...